# import a assembly using import-module for all powershell instances

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Can i import a assembly using import-module myabc.dll and it should be available for all the Powershell prompts opened or will be opened after sometime frame

I tried with -Scope Global, but it didnot work.

I am not sure if this is possible as it "Adds modules to the current session"

Is there any other command i can try ?

Comment: No, it'll only apply to the session in which you imported the module

Comment: Being able to modify loaded assemblies in the appdomain of another process would be a huge violation of the security model in Windows (and common sense) - what makes you think this would be possible and/or a good idea?

Comment: `Import-Module` imports a module _only into the current session_. To import the module into all sessions, add an `Import-Module` command to your Windows PowerShell profile. For more information about profiles, see [about_Profiles](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113729).

Answer (score 0):

You can add code to this file:

```
$Home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profile.ps1
```

What ever code you enter here will be executed every time you start PowerShell